# VBScript loop files in folder and kill proces

Tags: file, loops, vbscript

Hi I'm new with vbscript, I want to make a loop but I can't found how.

I want the script to loop through all files in a folder al called: 0001.ifc, 0002.ifc, etc.

The script has to open 0001.ifc, than wait to load, make a screenshot, kill the process and start over with file 0002.ifc.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\0001.ifc""")
WScript.Sleep 20000
WshShell.SendKeys "^{F11}"
' kill process Solibri Model Checker v9.5.exe, I have to figure out this also
```

Can anybody help me? Or point me to a website with tutorials for this?

Comment: Please start by explaining your code: what doesn't work, and what do you need help with specifically

Comment: You have three tasks. **1)** Find out how to write a loop in VBScript. That's easy. **2)** Find out how to list files in VBScript. That's easy. All of the examples you will find for that will even probably contain a loop. **3)** Find out how to kill a program in VBScript. That's easy, too. So you have three easy tasks that you can solve yourself even as a beginner. I suggest you try first.